# Django views-calling data from models.py and showing it

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to show what I have in models.py on the page postlogin.html but even if there's data in the database, the page doesn't show anything. I think I'm having trouble calling the data with the part(posts = NewRecipePost.objects.all().order_by("-post_date")) in views.py. the code below is only part of the code and everything is correctly imported and correctly indented.

I'd appreciate your advice. Thanks

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class NewRecipePost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', blank=False, max_length=50 )
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    ingredients = models.TextField('ingredients', max_length=1000)
    content = models.TextField('content', max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from recipeapp.models import NewRecipePost

class NewRecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = NewRecipePost
```

views.py

def my_view(request,username):

```
posts = NewRecipePost.objects.all().order_by("-post_date")

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewRecipeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
else:
    form = NewRecipeForm()
variables = RequestContext(request, {'form':form,'username':username, 'posts':posts})

return render_to_response('postlogin.html',variables)
```

postlogin.html

```
            <ul>
                {% for post in posts.object_list %}
                    <div>{{post.title}}</div>
                    <div>{{post.post_date}}</div>
                    <ul>
                        <div>{{post.ingredients}}</div>
                        <div>{{post.content}}</div>
                    </ul>
                {% endfor %}

            </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`posts.object_list` doesn't exist. You only use `object_list` with a `Paginator` instance, which you haven't set up. Just change it to `{% for post in posts %}` and you're good.